# String to datetime return nothing

Tags: php

i'm trying to convert a string into a datetime. There a lot of threads on this, but it does not seem to work. Nothing is returned. i've several things. What am i doing wrong? This is my object

```
$obj[0]['time']
```

this returns:

```
20/04/2014 10:13
```

which i would like to convert into a Date time since i need to sort by it.

i've tried following which i found on another thread. Why is it not returning it as a date time? i've also tried date_create_from_format, but cant get it to work.

```
$date = strtotime($obj[0]['time']);
echo $date;
```

Comment: What you are expecting from `strtotime`?

Comment: Do you want [`new DateTime($obj[0]['time'])`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Comment: `var_dump($date)`. if it says boolean false, then strtotime failed to figure out the format of your string.

Comment: PHP Docs: **Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components** Also **To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates**

Comment: it returns bool(false). What do i then need to do in order to make it figure it out

Comment: @user3423384 Just try to replace `/` with `-`. Like this: `str_replace('/', '-', $obj[0]['time']);` It should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over it in the object property then change it to a better format. If not `str_replace` `/` with `-`.  When `/` is used M/D/Y is expected.  Use `-` for D-M-Y since obviously 20 is not a valid month:

```
$date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-' , '20/04/2014 10:13');
```

The best bet is normally `YYYY-MM-DD`.  It is unambiguous and is easily sortable.

Comment: this returns int(1400266200) does this mean it works?